# Habilitar módulo mysqli en PHP 7.0.27 en windows (XAMPP)

Tags: php, mysqli, apache, xampp

Tengo instalado un XAMPP que traía por defecto PHP 5.6.24 y me he descargado otro XAMPP con PHP 7.0.27, lo que he hecho es copiar la carpeta `php` del nuevo xampp y la he pegado en el xampp antiguo (de manera que la carpeta original de `php` la he llamado `php5` y la nueva `php`), también he configurado el archivo `httpd-xampp.conf` para que cargue el modulo de php7 y he reiniciado XAMPP. De manera que ahora tengo la nueva versión de PHP.

Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es que el módulo de mysqli no está activado. Sin embargo en la carpeta `C:\xampp\php\ext` sí está el archivo `php_mysqli.dll` y en `php.ini` está la línea `extension=php_mysqli.dll` (y no está comentada). Por supuesto he reiniciado el apache varias veces.

Mi problema es que no se si me falta un paso para activar el módulo o algo estoy haciendo mal.

PD: se que lo fácil sería desinstalar el XAMPP antiguo y quedarme con el nuevo pero necesito trabajar con ambas versiones

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por si te sirve http://www.wampserver.com/en/ te permite alternar entre versiones de PHP.

Comment: Hola! Yo también acostumbraba hacerlo como has descrito, pero leyendo ahora la documentación de PHP, respecto a habilitación de extensiones, dice que con la versión 7.2 en adelante ha cambiado un poco la manera. Sé que tu versión es anterior, pero no pierdes nada con mirar este link http://php.net/manual/es/install.pecl.windows.php ;)

Comment: Gracias por la información, pero de todas formas he vuelto a copiar la carpeta de php y ya funciona :), no se donde estaría el fallo